# How do I ssh into a GCP compute engine instance from circleci?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, continuous-delivery, circleci-2.0

I'm using circleci 2.0 and I'm trying to have circleci enter a gcp instance via ssh and fire off a deployment script with this command

```
sudo /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute ssh instance-1 
--command=/home/deploy_staging.sh --zone=us-east1-b
```

Doing this from my local machine works just fine, but when I try to do it from circleci I get this error:

```
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s)
```

Obviously it's ssh issues. I read something about putting ssh keys in the instance on gcp, and I have put my local machine's ssh keys there, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea why ssh from circleci is so cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official CircleCI documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/#ssh), you first need to add the SSH key for the server in the CircleCI application - this can be done on your project’s settings and under the SSH Permissions section.

Answer (score 3):

```
gcloud \
  --quiet \
  --project="${PROJECT}" \
  compute ssh "${INSTANCE_NAME}" \
  --zone "${ZONE}" \
  --strict-host-key-checking=no \
  --command "echo works"
```

`--quiet` is all you need and it will generate a key if one is not available. I am using this with a service account.

```
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:un2aZmExTGVD0KvebEVqAujrlXoAb0u7jO3Z5boCWaA root@581dc589b7fa
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|        .==      |
|  .     ....     |
| . . . o   .     |
|E . o . + . .    |
|   *   .S+ o     |
|  o *  o= o .    |
|   + =+o.* .     |
|   +==.=+.=      |
|  .oO+===+       |
+----[SHA256]-----+
WARNING: Using OS Login user [sa_102839341411404994442] instead of default user [root]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first activate the service account in a previous step instead:

```
          - run:
          name: Activate GCP Service Account
          resource_class: medium
          command: |
            echo $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_INTEGRATION | gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=-
            gcloud --quiet config set project ${GCP_PROJECT_ID_INTEGRATION}
```

Then execute `gcloud` with `--quiet``